# Memory tradeoff on ActiveRecord mass create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, memory, activerecord

> running Psql 9, Ruby 2.4 and Rails 5.x

Memory wise, which code would be better?

```
object_with_huge_texts.each do |x|
  MyModel.create(text_col: x.huge_text)
end
```

versus

```
values = Array.new
object_with_huge_texts.each do |x|
  values.push("(" << x.huge_text << ")")
end
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
 "INSERT INTO my_model (text_col) VALUES '#{values.join(",")}'"
)
```

I understand that the second option will be 1 sql query vs n+1.
But will the giant `values` array cause too big a memory bloat?

Comment: Use `[ ]` in preference to `Array.new` as it's less verbose. The explicit initializer is only necessary to pre-size or pre-populate the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how "huge" this data is. I've used servers with >1TB of memory and even a thrifty $5/mo. VPS still has >1GB in most cases, so it's all relative.

The first version benefits from garbage collection, as each model is created Ruby can discard the data, but there's additional overhead for the model itself.

The second version requires composing a potentially huge SQL string and smashing it in all at once. This could be problematic for two reasons: Your Ruby memory footprint might be too large, or your database might reject the query as being too big. The Postgres default "max query size" is typically 1GB.

If you're doing bulk loads on a regular basis and need it to be efficient you could try using a prepared statement with a placeholder value, then supply different values when executing. This scales quite well and performance is usually comparable to multi-insert style operations so long as there's not a lot of index pressure on the data.

Comment: For context,  this is a zip import. Each text is about 10kb

Comment: For context,  this is a zip import. Each text is about 10kb

Comment: 10KB is basically nothing these days.

Comment: Yeah, i am importing zip files with thousands of 10kb text files. ~50mb compacted.. thats my concern, but I followed your advice, lets see how it goes